# If |A|=|B|, then $|P(A)|=|P(B)|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

If $|A|=|B|$, then $|P(A)|=|P(B)|$

This is what I have done so far:

Assume $|A|=|B| \Rightarrow \exists$ a bijection $f:A \to B$

Define $F: P(A) \to P(B)$ where $ F(S)=\{f(a)| a\in S\}\subseteq B $

Claim: $F$ is injective

Suppse $ F(S)=F(S') \Rightarrow s=s'$. Let $$ a \in S \Rightarrow f(a) \in F(S)=F(S') \Rightarrow f(a) \in F(S')= \{f(b)| b \in S'\}=$$

This is where I get stuck. Should I show $ \exists b \in S'$ such that $f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$. Since $a \in S, $ then $a=b \in S' \Rightarrow a \in S'$. Does this prove that $s=s'$ ?

Claim: $F$ is surjective

Since $F(S) \subset B $, then $ F(S) \in P(B) $ for all $ b \in B,  \exists$ a unique $f^{-1} (b) \in A$.

So $$F(\{f^{-1}(b): b \in B\})= \{f(f^{-1}(b))| b \in B\}=\{b |b \in B\}=B$$

So, $F$ is surjective.

Comment: I know I probably did something wrong here. Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I've done my best to clean up your post. Please read it and make sure I didn't change anything. I would strongly recommend reading an introductory LaTeX tutorial before you post another symbolically-heavy question

Comment: I thought I did pretty good of using math notation here.

Comment: The issue wasn't the notation, it was the typesetting. Rule 1 of LaTeX is never use $ in the middle of an equation. You can click "edit" to see how I got your equations to render properly, and you can compare to your version by looking at past edits.

Answer (score 2):

$F$ is injective.

Suppose $F(S)=F(S')$. Let $a\in S$; then $f(s)\in F(S)$, so $f(s)\in F(S')$. Then there exists $s'\in S'$ with $f(s')=f(s)$. Since $f$ is injective, $s=s'$, so $s\in S'$. Hence $S\subseteq S'$. By symmetry, $S'\subseteq S$. (You just need to clean up a bit, but your idea is good.)

$F$ is surjective.

Let $T\subseteq B$. Then consider $S=f^{-1}(T)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in T\}$ and prove $F(S)=T$.